# Cloudflare warp and docker ssl termination at the host

Tags: networking, docker, cloudflare

I am trying to set up cloudflare and docker such that SSL termination happens on the host and not on the docker containers themselves. This is useful because I want docker containers to be able to perform requests over the internet without having to install the Cloudflare certificates to the docker containers.
I also don't want the hassle of having to install docker certs on all containers I download from this internet in the future.

Is there a way to get SSL to terminate at the host and for docker to be usable without the SSL certificates of cloudflare?

So far I have tried setting the cloudflare warp proxy in local proxy mode, this enables a socks5 proxy on the localhost, but still requires an ssl certificate to be in the containers as they are the connecting service.
I have also tried various configuration options within the cloudflare UI including split tunnel rules. However, you cannot direct the split tunnel to an application.
Finally I tried implementing `pproxy` within docker but this did not help, my thought was set this up and proxy traffic through this docker instance.

##### Additional notes

- Running on local dev machine
- Full admin access
- OSX (primarily)

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried so far? Can you add this info to your question?

Comment: @music2myear updated

Comment: Is this all running on a local computer on your network, or on a VPS or other hosted system?

Comment: All on the local machine @music2myear